# Datetime aritmethics in sqlite on android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to do some datetime aritmethics in Sqllite. I have a table with two rows defined as type `DATETIME`. These fields are called LOG_FROM and LOG_TO. In a query on this table I try to do the following:

```
SELECT SUM(LOG_FROM - LOG_TO) AS TIMESPENT FROM LOG_TABLE WHERE X=Y;
```

This subtraction inside the `SUM` function does not work as intended. It will always return the number 0. I read the data via a cursor.getString.

When I store dates in the table I convert them to strings on the format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite [ignores column data types](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html). Your date strings are strings.

Your date format is supported by the [built-in date functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html), so you can use them to convert the dates to numbers.
Assuming that you want the result to be a number of days, use `julianday`:

```
SELECT SUM(julianday(LOG_TO) - julianday(LOG_FROM)) ...
```

Comment: how about if I want to include hours and minutes?

Comment: Are included as fractional values.